# OPENMP taskyield directive not yielding tasks in hybrid (openmp + mpi) program

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp, yield

There are two tasks.
One communicates through mpi and the other does some cool stuff. 
I use mpi non-blocking calls in order to allow the running thread to execute other tasks while waiting for the information. 
But it doesn't work.

A little of explanation of the code. If you wish you can jump straight to the code.
It creates two processes.
The first process will sleep for 10 seconds and then send some data through a blocking call.
The second process (this is the process of interest) will create two threads with a shared integer (done). One task will be instantiated once, and the other one will be instantiated as many times as threads there are (in this case 2).
The first task will receive data using a non-blocking call and should yield so the running thread can execute the another task (but this doesn't happen). This task is run by only one thread.
The second task just prints some cool stuff. This task is instantiated by both threads.

Here is the code:

```
if (rank == 0)
  {
    buffer[1000] = 5;
    sleep(10);
    printf("Process %d sent data\n", rank);
    MPI_Send(buffer, SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  else if (rank == 1)
  {
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) shared (done)
    {
#pragma omp single nowait
      {
#pragma omp task
        {
          int flag = 0;
          printf("Thread %d is receiving data\n", omp_get_thread_num());
          MPI_Irecv(buffer, SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

          MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
          while (flag == 0)
          {
            #pragma omp taskyield
            MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
            printf("Thread %d is wasting time\n", omp_get_thread_num());
            sleep(1);
          }

          done=1;
          printf("Thread %d received data\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        }
      }

#pragma omp task 
      {
        printf("Thread %d entered to the cool task\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        while (done == 0)
        {
          printf("Thread %d is doing some cool stuff\n", omp_get_thread_num());
          sleep(1); /* Or not */
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is the output:

```
Thread 0 is receiving data
Thread 1 entered to the cool task
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Process 0 sent data
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 is wasting time
Thread 1 is doing some cool stuff
Thread 0 received data
Thread 0 entered to the cool task
```

As you can see Thread 0 doesn't enter the cool task until it finishes with the communication task.

Compilation command:

```
mpicc -fopenmp pruebas.c -o prueba
```

Execution command:

```
mpirun -np 2 --allow-run-as-root ./prueba (worry not, read below)
```

Other information:

```
The program is being ran in a docker container with ubuntu.
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)
mpicc --show output: gcc -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2021/libevent -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2021/libevent/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenMP specification does not **require** that `taskyield` does anything, it says

> The taskyield construct specifies that the current task **can** be suspended in favor of execution of a different task.

So it **allows** re-scheduling but does not require it. (The task-scheduling alogorithm description is also clear on this point). Therefore gcc is entirely within its rights not to reschedule.

I do, though, know that the LLVM (and Intel) OpenMP runtime does yield, and we can see that [gcc is generating a call into the runtime](https://godbolt.org/g/JDg4fC), so there's a chance that just using the LLVM runtime with your binary would be sufficient. Alternatively, try clang or [the Intel compilers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software)

(Full disclosutre: I work for Intel :-))